# Jest + Vue3 + @Vueform/slider "SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module"

Tags: vue.js, jestjs, vuejs3, babel-jest

I'm using Jest as a test runner in a Vue 3 project that makes use of the @vueform slider plugin:

https://github.com/vueform/slider

the code in @vueform/slider/dist/slider.js:1 tiggers a "SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module" error.

I've tried adding a "transformIgnorePatterns" entry in the package.json's Jest configuraiton:

```
"jest": {
  "testEnvironment": "jsdom",
  "moduleFileExtensions": [
    "js",
    "json",
    "vue"
  ],
  "transform": {
    "^.+\\.(js|jsx)$": "babel-jest",
    "^.+\\.(vue)$": "vue3-jest"
  },
  "transformIgnorePatterns": ["/node_modules/(?!@vueform/slider/)", "node_modules/(?!@vueform/)"]
}
```

I Also added "type": "module" to package.json

And tried changing

```
import SliderPrice from "@vueform/slider"
```

to

```
const SliderPrice = require("@vueform/slider")
```

Still getting the same error!

Any ideas how I can solve this issue? I can't test anything with Jest until this error gets sorted.

### Edit:

I forgot to add this: Intially, the error message details included the entire (minimized) slider.js file. After adding "type": "module" to package.json the details now include just this line:

```
({"Object.<anonymous>":function(module,exports,require,__dirname,__filename,jest){import { toRefs as t, ref as e, computed as r, reactive as n, onMounted as i, onUnmounted as o, watch as a, openBlock as s, createBlock as l, mergeProps as u } from "vue";
```

### Edit 2:

My babel config is in a .babelrc file:

```
{
  "presets": ["@babel/preset-env"]
}
```

- Vue is the front end setup within a Laravel application, but the webpack.mix.js configuration file doesn't use babel.

### Edit 3:

After a few more hours of playing around with the settings, I believe that this is Babel related:
If I delete my .babelrc file then I start getting the "SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module" error for my own .vue files. This shows that with the .babelrc file, my ES6 javascript files are being transformed to ES5.

So the Vue plugins, like @vueform/slider/ are NOT being transformed to ES5 by Babel, even though the correct path is defined in "transformIgnorePatterns"

Comment: This might not be a solution but i think it is something worth trying. Your usage of `transformIgnorePatterns` seem dangerous. Read [this part of Jest docs](https://jestjs.io/docs/tutorial-react-native#transformignorepatterns-customization): *`transformIgnorePatterns` will exclude a file from transformation if the path matches against any pattern provided. Splitting into multiple patterns could therefore have unintended results if you are not careful.*

Comment: I know comments aren't supposed to be used for this, but have you found the solution? I'm currently having the same problem

Comment: @Nicole, I left it for a few days, then came back fresh to give it another go. I believe I have identified the root of the problem, although I haven't found a solution yet. I'll update this thread by tomorrow hopefully with a solution. Don't worry it'll get sorted one way or the other very soon :)

Comment: @LiamArbel did you ever resolve this?

Answer (score 0):

For **vue3** and 2 (I didn't test it on 2 but should work)

```sh
npm i -D @babel/preset-env babel-jest
```

### babel.config.js

```js
{
  "presets": ["@babel/preset-env"]
}
```

I have had issues also with vue files. Below my configuration works ok.

```sh
npm i -D @vue/vue3-jest # or 2 if you are on second version
```

### jest.config.js

```js
export default {
  testEnvironment: 'jsdom',
  transform: {
    '^.+\\.[t|j]sx?$': 'babel-jest',
    '^.+\\.vue$': '@vue/vue3-jest',
  },
}
```